# Inserting slides on jquery blog

Tags: jquery, web, blogs

How do I insert the following jquery slide

http://www.bloggermint.com/2010/02/featured-content-slider-for-blogger-using-jquery/

on my site? http://grandeportal.blogspot.com/
I'm having trouble because it has no content-wrapper on my site.